# In Vim, what is Control + W for in insert mode?

Tags: vim

If I'm in insert mode in Vim, and I press `Control + W`, it waits a moment, then deletes the previous word. If I start typing immediately after pressing it, it deletes the previous word instantly and replaces it with what I type.

In either case, the previous word is deleted and whatever I type next replaces it. So why the pause? Is there something else I can do at that point?

### Update

This is on MacVim 7.3 (55) on OSX Snow Leopard. I just logged into a server with a vanilla config and tried it, and the deletion is instant. So maybe it's something with my config?

Comment: I can't reproduce the delay.  What version of Vim and what operating system?

Comment: @Mikel - updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have a mapping that starts with Ctrl-W and that's why Vim waits for a while to see if you want to use it, check with `:verbose imap <C-W>`

Comment: Yep! This was in my .vimrc, which I intially got from a friend and have been tweaking since:

`imap <C-w><C-w> <esc><C-w><C-w>`

So he specifically mapped hitting "control + w" twice in insert mode to moving to the next window.

Comment: Using `imap` for `<C-w>` in insert mode is really useful, I find; but in your case, the ambiguous key mapping is what's causing the weird delay.  (I'll post an answer to elaborate)

Comment: This is also handy for `:verbose map [insertKeynames]` and `:verbose cmap [insertKeynames]`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Raimondi alluded to](https://superuser.com/questions/252388/in-vim-what-is-control-w-for-in-insert-mode/252409#252409), your .vimrc has an ambiguous mapping for `<C-w>`.

What I find more useful is to just **completely** remap `Ctrl-w` to get the "change window" behavior I want:

`imap <C-w> <esc><C-w>`

Now, that allows me to still use `<C-w><C-w>` to go to the next window as your mapping did, *but* it allow allows me to use *all* of the  window movements (see `:help window-moving` in Vim).  To me, that's way more powerful, even though I lose the default `<C-w>` behavior.

Back to your delay, and ambiguous mapping.  You have one defined in your .vimrc, and one mapping built-in to Vim, so you have:

`imap <C-w> [built-in behavior: delete previous word]` (not real syntax, just for illustration)
`imap <C-w><C-w> <esc><C-w><C-w>`

While Vi did not allow such mappings at all, Vim can deal with ambiguous mappings; The description in `:help map-ambiguous` in Vim explains your situation well:

> ```
>                                                         map-ambiguous
> When two mappings start with the same sequence of characters, they are
> ambiguous.  Example:
>     :imap aa foo
>     :imap aaa bar
> When Vim has read "aa", it will need to get another character to be able to
> decide if "aa" or "aaa" should be mapped.  This means that after typing > "aa"
> that mapping won't get expanded yet, Vim is waiting for another character.
> If you type a space, then "foo" will get inserted, plus the space.  If you
> type "a", then "bar" will get inserted. 
> {Vi does not allow ambiguous mappings}
> ```

If you want to keep the `<C-w>` behavior available, your best bet is to probably map it to Ctrl-Backspace.  It's not intuitive to do so, but per https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-Backspace_to_delete_previous_word it is possible:

> Mapping Ctrl-Backspace does not work in terminal Vim. Following is a
> workaround.
>
> ```
> noremap! <C-BS> <C-w>
> noremap! <C-h> <C-w>
> ```